# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found on IIS 10 on Windows Svr 2019

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, iis-10

***Old Environment***

- I have old application built on .net 2.0, 32 bit which is running fine on old servers.

***New Environment***

- In fact on new server I have configured same application under "default-app-pool" with ".net v2.0" and "Enabling 32-bit application" for default app pool. It is also running.

1. Then, I rebuild application with Framework 4.0, Any CPU.

- IIS - Added my application under "Classic .Net App Pool", with v4.0, "Enable 32-Bit App=true". [Just wanted to keep it under separate app pool since old application is running under DefaultAP.]
  And "Managed Pipeline Mode=Integrated".
- I have already installed versions in "Add role and Features Wizard" - .NET Framework 3.5, and 4.7 features.
- In the browser it gives me following error.

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

2. If I switch "Classic App Pool" to v2.0 then I get following error. Which is obvious that my dlls are now build with framework v4.0.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I want to deploy the application with new changes with 4.0 or 4.6 version on new environment. I have admin rights on environment. What should be missing?
Thanks.

Comment: What Windows version was used on your old servers?

Comment: @Lex Li: Old server is "Win2003R2 SP2", IIS-6

Comment: IIS 6 is equivalent to classic pipeline mode on IIS 10, so your migration should be in a strict order: 1) .NET CLR 2.0 classic mode on IIS 10. 2) (optional) .NET CLR 2.0 integrated mode, which has [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis). 3) (optional) .NET CLR 4.0 integrated mode, which has tons of [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes). Don't skip any step as you are going to handle too many changes altogether.

Comment: Thanks Lex. This may be long term plan. Let me try building site with framework2.0 and deploy.

Comment: Has the problem been solved using framework2.0?

Comment: On hold, but will do and update the comment ASAP.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please share your solution.